# Difference between set and hash?

Tags: ruby

Seems to me like the only real difference between a `hash` and a `set` is that sets don't have keys. Are there any other important differences?

Comment: Nah, sets don't have __values__. They have only keys :) (internally, ruby sets are implemented with hashes)

Comment: Well, it implies in a lot of differences... Be more specific please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all hashes are sets, but a hash can be used as a set.

Sets are collections where the values are...

- Unordered
- Unique

A hash with only keys matches that, so sets are often implemented as a hash with only keys. The keys are used as the values in the set, so they can be quickly looked up and iterated through.

In Perl it's very common to put a list into a hash to deduplicate it and work with it as a set.

```
my %set = map { $_ => 1 } @values;
```

Ruby's Set class is a thin wrapper around a hash. For example, here's [Set#add](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add).

```
# File set.rb, line 312
def add(o)
  @hash[o] = true
  self
end
```

If you want to check if something is in the set, just check if its in the hash, an O(1) lookup.

```
# File set.rb, line 214
def include?(o)
  @hash[o]
end
```

Most set operations, such as intersections and unions are very fast. Intersection just checks if any keys in one hash are in the other, an O(n) operation (leaving aside key collisions). Here's how Ruby does it.

```
def intersect?(set)
  set.is_a?(Set) or raise ArgumentError, "value must be a set"
  if size < set.size
    any? { |o| set.include?(o) }
  else
    set.any? { |o| include?(o) }
  end
end
```

Union combines both hashes into one new hash, also an O(n) operation.

```
def |(enum)
  dup.merge(enum)
end
```

Comment: I was confused by your reference to `both hashes` in your last line of text.